# How do I attach an event listener to the "max" Avatar in Mui's AvatarGroup?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to attach an event listener to the "max" Avatar specifically in the AvatarGroup, I know I can style the element but don't have access to the element to add an `onClick`. Here is the code snippet -

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Avatar from "@mui/material/Avatar";
import AvatarGroup from "@mui/material/AvatarGroup";

export default function GroupAvatars() {
  const names = [
    "Remy Sharp",
    "Travis Howard",
    "Cindy Baker",
    "Agnes Walker",
    "Trevor Henderson"
  ];
  return (
    <AvatarGroup onClick={(e) => console.log(e.currentTarget)} max={4}>
      {names.map((name, i) => {
        return <Avatar alt={name} src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg" />;
      })}
    </AvatarGroup>
  );
}
```

And here is the codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-curie-m43vvs?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62783008/5766429
It is the same concept you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

According to AvatarGroup API you can use

```
<AvatarGroup 
   slotProps={{
     additionalAvatar: {
       onClick: handleClick,
     }
    }}
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to access the outerText of the event target, so in this case can add a check to the AvatarGroup onClick function so `onClick = ((e) => { if(e.target.outerText.includes('+')) doSomethingAppropriate })`